# stack 2 useQuery and return 1 set of data react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have 2 useqQuery hooks, both fetching data from different endpoints. I will be using the same data in 1 component. It's essentially a form and I am populating the data.

Is there a way to stack the 2 queries and return 1 object/array of data which I can use in my component? I am happy to use 2 queries but wondered if there was a more optimal way.

Example of my 2 hooks and how they are used:

```
 export const useFetchCompanyIntegration = (integrationId) => {
    return useQuery([companies.fetchCompanyIntegration, integrationId],
        async () => {
            const { data } = await axios({
                url: url,
                method: "get",
                responseType: "json"
            });
            return data;
        }
    );
};

export const useFetchCompanyByID = (companyId) => {
    return useQuery([companies.fetchCompanyByID, companyId],
        async () => {
            const { data } = await axios({
                url: url,
                method: "get",
                responseType: "json"
            });
            return data;
        }
    );
};
```

```
    // grab stuff from companyIntegrationData 
    
    const {
        data: companyIntegrationData,
        isLoading: companyIntegrationIsLoading
    } = useFetchCompanyIntegration(integrationProp.id);

    // grab stuff from companyData 

    const {
        data: companyData,
        isLoading: companyDataIsLoading
    } = useFetchCompanyByID(currentCompany.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correctly. In some cases, I've needed to combine the two into a single hook.

There isn't a helper utility to do it for you, but the way that I like to do it is like this:

```js
useCombined(args) {
   const query1 = useQuery1();
   const query2 = useQuery2();
   return { 
            data: query1.data + query2.data, // Meaningfully combine the two datasets 
            isLoading: query1.isLoading || query2.isLoading, 
            isFetching: query1.isFetching || query2.isFetching
          }
}
```

You don't need to go overboard with the structure you return. I would extend the returned data as I need it, but it helps to mirror the react-query api for consistency.